# Cómo contar los días laborales entre 2 líneas de una consulta?

Tags: sql

Necesitaría saber si es posible crear un campo para calcular los días laborales que hay entre dos fechas de dos líneas de una consulta.

Lo explico con la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea sería crear un campo al lado que vaya contando los días laborales entre las fechas sucesivas, por ejemplo: entre el `2022-01-27` y el `2022-03-02`, entre el `2022-03-02` y el `2022-05-10` y así sucesivamente.

Comment: Qué motor de bd usas? Recuerda usar las etiquetas para indicarlo. Puedes [edit] la pregunta para incluir esta info

Comment: Una pregunta interesante. Y ¿Cómo defines lo que es un día laboral?.....Si eres capaz de dar una definición a la pregunta, quizá sea posible, pero como la respuesta, puede ser muy variable en función del país, la zona, a que empresa pertenezcas, cuál es la jornada del convenio....no se....yo diría que es bastante compleja.

Comment: Si la respuesta es, que como día laborable, va de lunes a viernes ambos inclusive y no se tienen en cuenta festivos, por ejemplo, en función del motor, puede haber posibles soluciones.